# Partition switch out switch in

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-partitioning

I am working on an archiving scenario in which a table partitioned by date (monthly intervals) is chopped one by one months at the "tail". However I want to be able to switch back in the last month switched out. So lasts month staging table it's to be switched back in at any moment until the next month switching. When I test this through graphic interface I have no problem switching out to staging however switching back it's not possible since there is no empty partition. How can the switching back can be accomplished without manually making another split in partition function to have an empty partition

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I found the answer for this. If you switch out a partition through ssms graphical interface it automatically issues a partition function merge range statement and deletes the partition instead of leaving it empty

Comment: . . If you know the answer to your own question, either delete the question or add an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the ssms graphic interface to switch out partitions the script generated includes a partition function merge statement which deletes the partition switched instead of leaving it empty for the switch back in